# Infinite loop while using call-with-current-continuation in Scheme

Tags: scheme, infinite-loop, continuations, callcc

I have been reading about `call-with-current-continuation` particularly in Scheme and have read various articles on many websites. However, I still don't understand how does the control flow work while using `call-with-current-continuation`.

For example, given the below attached code, how is the continuation invoked and whenever it is invoked, how does the control flow through the body of this procedure?

```
 (define call/cc call-with-current-continuation)
 (define showit (lambda (a b) 
                  (begin (display a) (display b) (display " "))))

 (define f
  (lambda (n)
     (let ((p (call/cc (lambda (k) k))))
         (begin
           (showit ’f= n)
          p))))
```

Also, when this procedure is run using `((f 2) (f 4))` it results in infinite loop with the pattern like this:

[image]

Can anyone explain the reason behind the infinite loop? 
Note: Using Drracket with R5RS

Answer (score 0):

Call/cc returns a function that continues the surrounding computation. When it is called, control is returned to the place where the function was taken from, with a value that is given to the function.

In the example, `(let ((p (call/cc (lambda (k) k)))) ...)`, p is given a continuation function. If p was then called `(p 3)`, the control would have returned to the `let`-form like it had been `(let ((p 3)) ...)`.

`((f 2) (f 4))` juggles the continuations from (f 2) and (f 4), which results in the infinite loop. I've tried to explain the flow below:

```
=> ((f 2) (f 4))
  => (f 2) ;; first (f 2)
       call/cc returns the current continuation (lets say "cc1") into p
       display f=2
       return cc1
=> (cc1 (f 4))
  => (f 4) ;; first (f 4)
       call/cc returns the current continuation cc2 into p
       display f=4
       return cc2
=> (cc1 cc2)
     cc1 goes back to the first (f 2), but call/cc returns now cc2 into p
     display f=2
     returns cc2 from the first (f 2)
=> (cc2 (f 4))
  => (f 4) ;; second (f 4)
       call/cc returns cc3 into p
       display f=4
       return cc3
=> (cc2 cc3)
     cc2 goes back to the first (f 4), but p gets cc3
     display f=4
     returns cc3 from the first (f 4)
=> (cc1 cc3)
     cc1 goes back to the first (f 2), but p gets cc3
     display f=2
     returns cc3 from the first (f 2)
=> (cc3 (f 4))
  => (f 4) ;; third (f 4)
       display f=4
  <= cc4
=> (cc3 cc4)
  => (f 4) ;; second again
       display f=4
  <= cc4
=> (cc2 cc4)
  => (f 4) ;; first again
       display f=4
  <= cc4
=> (cc1 cc4)
  => (f 2) ;; first again
       display f=2
  <= cc4
=> (cc4 (f 4))
  => (f 4) ;; fourth (f 4)
       display f=4
  <= cc5
...so on
```